# Limit SSL just for Login Page

Tags: java, servlets, ssl, authentication, tomcat7

How can I configure a Servlet to use SSL just for the Login Page and then use normal HTTP for the rest of the application.
If I make a special  for the login page requiring SSL, and one without for the rest of the pages, and I use form authentication with  pointing to the login page I configured before to use SSL, when the user requests a protected page, the URL in the Bar isn't login.page, it's the page requested, but the body is login form and I can login without using HTTPS.
Thanks..

Comment: Good question, my post (still unanswered) might be useful for you (declarative security) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442381/how-do-i-know-whether-httpservletrequest-is-subject-to-security-constraint-or-n

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite


Enjoy it!!

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry to say that, but it seems you want to do something wrong. Why you need https after user log-in, is that without it session could be easily hijacked as session cookies are visible in plain text. Of course one would need to be in the same network or probably even spoof IP address, but with so many WiFi networks it is actually piece of cake (as most user doesn't really know how to secure them).

So unless you are deploying your application in control environment (LAN only, limited number of more or less users - but why would you need SSL in such case anyway?), you probably need https all the time.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I don't need https AFTER login, I need WHEN the user logins, to protect the password. But as I said in the question, when requesting the login page directly the server wants https, when requesting a page, I'm redirected to the login page, but I can login withouth HTTPS, I want the login page to be with HTTPS and after the user logins to be without HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

ServletRequest has a method to determine if the request was made on a secure channel. Your login page could check this value and redirect to an https URL.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure%28%29

Comment: The OP is not really asking how to distinguish between SSL and non-SSL requests. The OP is asking how to configure a webapp as such that only the login page uses SSL.

Comment: Can't this be done with declarative security ? Not programmatic security.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same requirement - we absolutely **must** have the login encrypted, because the password is being sent, but we **don't want** the rest of the communication encrypted becuase it's computationally intensive.

Tomcat 7 SSL Configuration How-To clearly says:

"Any pages that absolutely require a secured connection should check the protocol type associated with the page request and take the appropriate action if *https* is not specified."

This means that the responsibility to re-direct the non-encrypted login requests to a secure URL lies entirely on the login page itself. There is no administrative method in Tomcat to configure this outside of the servlet. Tough luck.
As a result of this, we have to request this feature from the application vendor, because is a commercial software package.

As a crude workaround that compromises on the second requirement is to disable the regular HTTP connector on port 8080 after enabling the HTTPS connector on port 8443 (for instance).